# Is it possible to call CodeIgniter's controller using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to call CodeIgniter's controller using php?

I'm thinking of calling the controller using php. I have a display all year calendar.

```
<table style="margin-left:-50px;width:1300px;" class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr class="blue">
                            <th style="width:67px;">
                                <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: -5px;">
                                    <select style="width:auto;" name="years" onchange="submit();">
                                    <?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++): ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo date('Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' year')); ?>" <?php echo ($dYear==date('Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' year'))?'selected':'');?>><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' year')); ?></option>
                                       <?php endfor; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>      
                            </th>

                            <th>Su</th>
                            <th>Mo</th>
                            <th>Tu</th>
                            <th>We</th>
                            <th>Th</th>
                            <th>Fr</th>
                            <th>Sa</th>
                            <th>Su</th>
                            <th>Mo</th>
                            <th>Tu</th>
                            <th>We</th>
                            <th>Th</th>
                            <th>Fr</th>
                            <th>Sa</th>
                            <th>Su</th>
                            <th>Mo</th>
                            <th>Tu</th>
                            <th>We</th>
                            <th>Th</th>
                            <th>Fr</th>
                            <th>Sa</th>
                            <th>Su</th>
                            <th>Mo</th>
                            <th>Tu</th>
                            <th>We</th>
                            <th>Th</th>
                            <th>Fr</th>
                            <th>Sa</th>
                            <th>Su</th>
                            <th>Mo</th>
                            <th>Tu</th>
                            <th>We</th>
                            <th>Th</th>
                            <th>Fr</th>
                            <th>Sa</th>
                            <th>Su</th>
                            <th>Mo</th>

                        </tr>                                   
                        <?php
                            function FriendlyDayOfWeek($dayNum) {
                            // converts the sunday to 7
                            // This function can be removed in php 5 by - date("N"),
                            // just remove function calls below and replace by swapping date("w" for date("N"
                            if ($dayNum == 0){ return 0; } else { return $dayNum; }
                            }

                            //inserting blank TDs
                            function InsertBlankTd($numberOfTdsToAdd) {
                            for($i=1;$i<=$numberOfTdsToAdd;$i++) {
                            $tdString .= "<td></td>";
                            }
                            return $tdString;
                            }


                            for ($mC=1;$mC<=12;$mC++) {
                            //for loop for inserting MONTHS
                            /*
                             * $mC = MONTH
                             * $dDay = DAY
                             * $dYear = YEAR
                             */
                            $currentDT = mktime(0,0,0,$mC,$dDay,$dYear);
                            $daysInMonth = date("t",$currentDT);
                            $dMonth = date("n",$currentDT);
                            //echo "<pre>".$daysInMonth."</pre>";
                            echo "<tr><td><div>".date("M",$currentDT)."</div></td>";


                            echo InsertBlankTd(FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$currentDT))-0);

                            //for loop for inserting DAYS.
                            for ($i=1;$i<=$daysInMonth;$i++) {
                            $exactDT = mktime(0,0,0,$mC,$i,$dYear);
                            $rHoliday = date("n-j",$exactDT); // repeating holidays
                            $nHoliday = date("Y-n-j",$exactDT); //non-repeating holidays
//check if holiday.
                            if ($holiday!=""){
                                foreach($holiday as $row){
                                    if ($row['repeats_annually'] == "Yes")
                                    {
                                        $h = explode("-", $row['date_stamp']); 
                                        $aHoliday = $h[1]."-".$h[2]; //annual holidays
                                        //echo "<pre>".$aHoliday."</pre>";
                                        //$class = ($aHoliday == $rHoliday?"green-box":"");
                                        if ($aHoliday == $rHoliday){
                                            echo '<pre>'.$aHoliday . ' = ' .$nHoliday.'</pre>';
                                            $class = 'green-box';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //echo "<pre>".date("Y-n-j",$exactDT)."</pre>";
                            //if ($i==date("d")&&date("m",$currentDT)==date("m")) { $class="currentDay"; } else { $class = ""; }
                            echo "<td class=''>".$i.$class."</td>";
                            }

                            echo InsertBlankTd($dDaysOnPage - $daysInMonth - FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$currentDT))-0);
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            ?>
                    </table>
```

now you'll see on my comment "//for loop for inserting DAYS.", you will see the another comment '//check if holiday.' in which i will put a class on that td and will make it color green if it's holiday. the problem is I think my algorithm is wrong on that. so i'm thinking that i will delete that foreach on the $holiday. and will just call the controller function in which every "day" will be compared and check if it's holiday instead of using foreach if it's possible to call the controller using php. but is there any other way to do it more simpler? or if not. it's also ok.

here's the controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class attendance extends CI_Controller {



public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('fill_in','fill');  //model fill in
    $this->load->model('mdl_employee','emp');
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');        
}


public function index()
{ 
    $account = $this->session->userdata('account_type');
    if ($account == '3' || $account == '1')
    {
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id'); 
    $data['info'] = $this->emp->get_myinfo($id);
    $data['holiday'] = $this->emp->get_holidays();
    $data['employee_header_menus'] = $this->load->view('employee_header_menus', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['employee_header_logout'] = $this->load->view('employee_header_logout', $data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('employee/attendance', $data);
    }
}
}
```

and the model for $data['holiday']

```
public function get_holidays()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('holidays');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                    'description' => $row->description,
                    'date_stamp' => $row->date_stamp,
                    'repeats_annually' => $row->repeats_annually
                );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data = "";
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: how about using the built in calendar?

Comment: you might call controller but I don't understand the point that is mvc structure and in controller you nothing but call library, model etc which can be easily accomplished by using `$CI =& get_instance();`

Comment: @tomexsans but the built-in calendar of codeigniter only show the months..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call specific functions on either a library or a helper. Controller's main purpose is to serve as a router; it is because it is also a class that many people "misuse" it (I do this, too - we all do) to include many related functions & call them with $this->myfunction()

Whether or not that's entirely appropriate I won't debate here, but the short answer is - use a library or helper function to do the type of thing you are after; call controllers only as you would call an actual page or api/ajax call.